# How can I display apache beam pipeline graph on UI

Tags: user-interface, apache-beam

I am direct runer in apache beam and I want to build my own dev ops UI , I am mostly done in my UI where I can show the pipeline details (failure / success ) can display metrics results etc .

What I am now interested in is to display the pipeline graph (DAG graph) which shows complete design of my running pipeline .

Appreciate you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to DataflowRunner code, it generates a pipeline json with all the worker steps and uploads it to cloud. Later, which is also referred to build a pipeline graph in GCP.

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowRunner.java

Comment: can you guide me to exact code , i can see DataflowPipelineTranslator which is just printing job to json string and uploading it .